# How to sort time in order?

Tags: python, sorting, timer, tkinter

I am new to python.
Basically i did this GUI is to record the Lap Timing of a Car. Once the car completed the 1st Lap, I am to record the timing of the lap. Subsequent laps need to be recorded too. The time recorded will appear on the Listbox. However, I do not know how to sort the timing from the fastest Lab time to the slowest Lab time. Anybody can help me?

```
from tkinter import *
import time

class StopWatch(Frame):  
     """ Implements a stop watch frame widget. """                                                                
        def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):        
            Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
            self._start = 0.0        
            self._elapsedtime = 0.0
            self._running = 0
            self.timestr = StringVar()
            self.e = 0
            self.m = 0
            self.makeWidgets()
            self.laps = []
            self.lapmod2 = 0
            self.today = time.strftime("%d %b %Y %H-%M-%S", time.localtime())

    def makeWidgets(self):                         
            """ Make the time label. """
            l1 = Label(self, text='----File Name----')
            l1.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=1, padx=2)

            self.e = Entry(self)
            self.e.pack(pady=2, padx=2)

            l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr)
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            l.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=3, padx=2)

            l2 = Label(self, text='----Laps----')
            l2.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=4, padx=2)

            scrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL)
            self.m = Listbox(self,selectmode=EXTENDED, height = 10,font=("Helvetica", 12),yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
            self.m.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1, pady=5, padx=2)
            scrollbar.config(command=self.m.yview)
            scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        def _update(self): 
            """ Update the label with elapsed time. """
            self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            self._timer = self.after(50, self._update)

        def _setTime(self, elap):
            """ Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
            minutes = int(elap/60)
            seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
            hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)                
            self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds, hseconds))

        def _setLapTime(self, elap):
            """ Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
            minutes = int(elap/60)
            seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
            hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)            
            return '%02d:%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds, hseconds)

        def Start(self):                                                     
            """ Start the stopwatch, ignore if running. """
            if not self._running:            
                    self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
                    self._update()
                    self._running = 1        

        def Stop(self):                                    
            """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
            if self._running:
                    self.after_cancel(self._timer)            
                    self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start    
                    self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
                    self._running = 0

        def Reset(self):                                  
            """ Reset the stopwatch. """
            self._start = time.time()         
            self._elapsedtime = 0.0
            self.laps = []   
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)

        def Lap(self):
            '''Makes a lap, only if started'''  
            tempo = self._elapsedtime - self.lapmod2
            if self._running:
                    self.laps.append(self._setLapTime(tempo))
                    self.m.insert(END, self.laps[-1])

                    self.m.yview_moveto(1)
                    self.lapmod2 = self._elapsedtime

        def GravaCSV(self):
            arquivo = str(self.e.get()) + ' - '
            with open(arquivo + self.today + '.txt', 'wb') as lapfile:
                    for Lap in self.laps:
                        lapfile.write((bytes(str(Lap) + '\n', 'utf-8')))


def main():
        root = Tk()
        root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)     
        sw = StopWatch(root)
        sw.pack(side=TOP)

        Button(root, text='Lap', command=sw.Lap).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(root, text='Start', command=sw.Start).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(root, text='Stop', command=sw.Stop).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(root, text='Reset', command=sw.Reset).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(root, text='Save', command=sw.GravaCSV).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=LEFT)    

        root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: What specific part of your code is the problem? Don't post a bunch of code that is irrelevant to the question you're asking.

Comment: @Erik Godard There are no problem with the code. Basically i do not know how to sort only. I am new to python and i got 0 knowledge abort sorting. That is the reason i need you people to help me.

Comment: What have you done to try and solve this problem? For example, have you looked up the word "sort" in the python documentation?

Comment: @BryanOakley Can i know what is the link which is helpful to my codes above?

Comment: This site alone has over 12,000 questions about sorting in python: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+sort+is%3Aquestion

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the elapsed time would be stored in a list and the list would then be sorted in whatever order you want.  I don't know if you do any of that already or not, but just as an easy example on an existing list try this and see the results in the file https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

```
    def GravaCSV(self):
        arquivo = str(self.e.get()) + ' - '
        self.laps.sort()
        """ next sort as numbers instead of strings (not tested)
            and then sort and write laps_as_num to file
        laps_as_num=[]
        for this_lap in laps:
            lap=this_lap.split(":")
            laps_as_num.append([int(lap[0]), int(lap[1]), int(lap[2])])
        """
        with open(arquivo + self.today + '.txt', 'wb') as lapfile:
                for Lap in self.laps:
                    lapfile.write((bytes(str(Lap) + '\n', 'utf-8')))
```